# Android: Market Developer Console "Device availability" doesn't work?

Tags: android, compatibility, google-play

I have tried "Device availability" in Android Market Developer Console, but I think that either it has a lot of bugs or it is misleading.

For testing it, I have uploaded a very simple application, whose manifest is as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.makeramen.segmented"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
</manifest>
```

I think that with this kind of manifest the app would be supported by most devices, as I have stated it to run on devices Android 1.6 and higher, don't request any special permissions and I state that it should run in any screen size.

When I upload the application to market, I see:
**This application is available to over 783 devices. Show devices**

Whenever I click "Show Devices", the "Device Availability" popup is shown, like this:

[image]

Whatever manufacturer / model I search for, I always get the "Unsupported devices due to your manifest" message. Example: if I search for "samsung", it seems like this basic application is incompatible with every existent samsung model:

[image]

**Is this normal? Do you have the same behaviour?**